# What does "was gonna be" means?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

So no one told your life was gonna be this way.

Is it used to say something would happen in the next future?

Comment: "gonna" - "going to". **No one told you that your life would turn out the way it is**. It's a statement about *now*, not the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really needed to understand that sentence.